# 2 classes for 1 div, class has space in name

Tags: html, css

I want to give a `div` 2 classes, however, one of the class names has a space in it. I want to give a div the `"section scrollspy"` class and `carousel` class.

Will putting a space in between classes still work?

**For example:**

```
<div class="section scrollspy carousel">
```

Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: space character in css name is invalid

Answer (score 3):

Spaces are invalid in class names, the normal way to do it is to use a hyphen instead of a space so it would be:

```
<div class="section-scrollspy carousel">
```

Theres a good post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/449000/1836618) that talks about valid CSS names.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to preserve the space character, you'll have to update your css :

```
.section.scrollspy {
   // css rules
}
```

but it's still two class here. If you want to use just one class, you'll have to use Peter Featherstone's answer :

> `<div class="section-scrollspy carousel">`